# A not that obvious proof of vector property

Tags: vectors

I want to show that if $\vec a  \cdot \vec b=0$, then there must be some vector $\vec x$ to let $\vec x\times\vec b=\vec a$ which $\vec a  ,\vec b,$ and $\vec x$ are not $\vec 0$ in $\Bbb R^3$.

The reverse is obvious. If $\vec x\times\vec b=\vec a$ then $\vec b\cdot(\vec x\times\vec b)=\vec b\cdot\vec a$

Where $\vec b\cdot(\vec x\times\vec b)=\vec x\cdot(\vec b\times\vec b)=0=\vec b\cdot\vec a$

But I don't find anything that is helpful to use $\vec a  \cdot \vec b=0$

I know this is the truth. Please don't give me an intuitive way, thanks.

Comment: Think about it geometrically: How is $\vec v\times\vec w$ related to $\vec v$ and $\vec w$? What does this tell you about potential candidates for $\vec x$ in your problem?

Comment: @amd I know they are perpendicular.

Comment: Yes, they are. So how does this restrict your search for an $\vec x$?

Comment: $\vec b \cdot (\vec x \times \vec b)=\vec b \cdot \vec a$ doesn't mean $\vec x \times \vec b=\vec a$

Comment: @amd But the asker didn't want an *intuitive* way. Your methods are far too intuitive! ;-)

Comment: @TheoBendit Hehe. For my part, once I’ve grasped the geometry of the situation, it’s a lot easier to write down some relevant equations and bash out a solution. This problem can certainly be solved purely analytically, say by rewriting the equation in the form $M\vec x=-\vec a$, but that kind of misses the point, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sketch:

- The case where $\vec{a}$ is $\vec{0}$ is trivial, so this case can be dealt with easily.
- The case where $\vec{b}$ is $\vec{0}$ is a counterexample (unless $\vec{a}$ also equals $\vec{0}$), so we must assume that $\vec{b}\not=\vec{0}$.
- Observe that $\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}=0$ means that $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ are perpendicular.  In particular, they point in different directions.
- Let $\vec{y}=\vec{a}\times\vec{b}$. Then, $\vec{y}$ is perpendicular to both $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$.  Since $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ do not point in the same direction, $\vec{y}$ is not $\vec{0}$.
- Consider $\vec{y}\times\vec{b}$.  This is a vector perpendicular to both $\vec{y}$ and $\vec{b}$.
- Note that the set of vectors perpendicular to both $\vec{y}$ and $\vec{b}$ are on a line.  This line includes $\vec{a}$.  Now, scale $\vec{y}$ appropriately to get $\vec{x}$.

Comment: So, we have a vector has a direction of $\vec a \times  \vec b$ and scale of $\frac{|\vec a|}{|\vec b|}$. Then we always have a vector $\vec x=\frac{\vec a \times \vec b}{|\vec b|^2}$

Comment: Let me show $\vec x \times \vec b=\vec a$

Comment: That should work (if it doesn't, then $-\vec{x}$ will work).  One has to think about the left/right order of the cross product in terms of the right-hand-rule to be sure of the choice of sign for the vector.